# Safer alternative to the use of as

Tags: typescript

I'm writing TypeScript code, at some point I need to take the output of HTTP call (basically a JSON string) and turn it into a typed object. I used `as` clause to do this job, something like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
    idUser: string;
    idProducts: string[];
}

const str: string = "{ \"idUser\": \"johndoe\", \"shadowKey\": \"myValue\" }";

const myObject = JSON.parse(str) as MyInterface;

console.log(myObject);
```

This works and the `console.log` instruction will print:

```
{
  "idUser": "johndoe",
  "shadowKey": "myValue"
}
```

I perfectly understand the rationale but I would like to have a safer approach. Something that will raise an error if `idProducts` field is not provided and will hide the `shadowKey` when printed.

What is the best/simplest way to achieve this in TypeScript?

Comment: What you're looking for is a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Comment: TypeScript cannot help more here. The structure of `myObject` is not known at compile time (where TS operates). The best that TS can help here is already done by using `as MyInterface`. It tells TS: _"hey, even if this looks like an object with unknown properties, trust me that it matches the `MyInterface` interface"_. At runtime, especially if `str` comes from outside the code (user input, values retrieved from database or another service etc), chances are that the object returned by `JSON.parse()` does not look like `MyInterface` at all. You have to write JS code to check its structure.

Comment: Btw, the value of `myObject` in the sample code does not match the `MyInterface` interface. The property `idProducts` is required in `MyInterface` but it is missing in `myObject`. This is something that TS cannot detect; one has to run the code to discover this and TS does not run the code.

Answer (score 2):

This can somewhat be achieved using [TS type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) (formerly known as [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)).

For this you need to define a function that returns a type predicate which checks whether or not the obj has the required elements.

```
interface MyInterface {
    idUser: string;
    idProducts: string[];
}

function isMyInterface(obj: Object): obj is MyInterface {
  return ("idUser" in obj && typeof obj.idUser === "string")   //obj.idUser exists and is a string
    && ("idProducts" in obj && Array.isArray(obj.idProducts)); //obj.idProducts exists and is an Array
}

const str: string = "{ \"idUser\": \"johndoe\", \"shadowKey\": \"myValue\" }";
const myObject: MyInterface = JSON.parse(str) as MyInterface;
if(isMyInterface(myObject)){ // will fail in this example
  console.log("myObject is MyInterface");
} else {
  console.log("myObject is not MyInterface");
}
```

This is almost a js solution here, except for the return type. We could just return a `boolean` result (which is in fact what the resulting js will work with). But with this setup ts will be able to interpret the result and be able to give you compile time errors/issues. e.g.

```
if(isMyInterface(myObject)){
  console.log(myObject.idProducts); // works
} else {
  console.log(myObject.idProducts); // Error: Property 'idProducts' does not exist on type 'never'.
}
```

Comment: `typeof obj.idUser === "string" && Array.isArray(obj.idProducts)` should be enough for the predicate. If `obj` does not have the property `idUser` then `obj.idUser` is `undefined` and its type is not `"string"`. Similar for `idProducts`, `undefined` is not an array.

Comment: ah yeah, that's true. Would simplify the code a bit, but I'd like to also include a generic "does this exist", as you cannot necessarily check for every type exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Zod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod) to validate your object.

Example object:

```
const ZodResult = z.object({
  idUser: z.string(),
  idProducts: z.array(z.string()),
});
```

Infer to use it as type:

```
type Result = z.infer<typeof ZodResult>;
```

Parse your object,

```
const parsed = JSON.parse(yourStringObject);
const result = ZodResult.safeParse(parsed);
if (!result.success) {
  // handle error then return
  result.error;
} else {
  // do something with data
  result.data; // data has type Result
}
```